# append method using the from inside an Jquery $getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Ok, so I have 3 files,
First a JSON file that tells me all the information that I need, 
A Html file that gives me like a skeleton of where to put all the javascript
A javascript file that will hook up the information from the JSON and put into the html.

So my HTML is something like:

```
<div class="hello">
  <h2>Name</h2>
</div>
```

My JSON is this with root to data/bio.json:

```
{
 "name" :  "Olivia Palito",
 "age" : "23"
}
```

My Javascript is like this:

```
var mockup = '<div class="work"></div>';
var mockup02 = '<div>%data%</div>';
var $addItem01 = $(".hello");
var $addItem02 = $(".work");
var jsonRoot = 'data/bio.json';
$.getJSON(jsonRoot, function(data){
   var addMe = mockup.replace('%data%', data.name);
   $addItem01.append(mockup);
   $addItem02.append(addMe);
});
```

Now the problem, 
When I run this on the browser, I can add the first mockup, and it will add the `<div class="work"></div>` but when I try to add also the addMe, it doesn't show anything. 
What am I missing here?
And if I put console.log(data); it will show something, which means that I am receiving the file, but it just not adding to the html, because I can add also static text, instead of using the replace method, and won't add the content.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mockup02 = mockup.replace(%data%, data.name);
```

It does not work because that is not valid JavaScript.

Open up the console and you should see the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %

You need to make it a regular expression

```
var mockup02 = mockup.replace(/%data%/, data.name);
```

or a string

```
var mockup02 = mockup.replace("%data%", data.name);
```

---

And the second reason it fails is you are selecting the element with the class `work` before it is added to the page. It does not magically find the element.

Switching it to and it will add it.

```
$(".work").append(addMe);
```

Comment: I am sorry epascarello, I just mistyped my question, if you could please take a look again, the problem that I am facing is not with the part where I have to replace the "%data%" for the content that is coming from the JSON file, more so the fact that I am trying to add to new things to the html , and it works on the first try, when I tag the .hello class, and append to it, but when I tried to append to the .work class that came with the last append, it doesn't work. I hope i could make myself clear.

Comment: And I added the reason why...You are looking for an element that does not exist. It is like someone calling your name before you show up. You are not going to respond since you are not there.

Comment: if you look at my code you will tell that I posted that. $addItem02.append(addMe); where $addItem02 it's a variable already created

Comment: I KNOW IT, read the explanation. There is NO ELEMENT with `.work` when you set it. `console.log($addItem02.length); //0`

Comment: Thank you man, now I got what you said, I was creating the variable for the div with the class work when there was no div with class work yet, now I changed that in order to only create that variable when the first div is added, Again thank you for the patience